# Cannot convert value of type 'CustomButton.Type' to expected argument type 'CustomButton'

Tags: swift, uibutton

So I keep getting this error( Cannot convert value of type 'CustomButton.Type' to expected argument type 'CustomButton')
its only on this line of code

```
    cell.productStatus.index = indexPath
    cell.productStatus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapCellButton(sender: CustomButton)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

I cannot figure out why this issue is here.
and this is how CustomButton is coded.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class CustomButton:UIButton{
var index:IndexPath?     }



 //
//  ViewController.swift
//  
//
 //  Created by  on 10/15/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Kadin Loehr. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import StoreKit
class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProductTableViewCell", bundle: nil)




NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes), name: NSNotification.Name.init("SKProductsHaveLoaded"), object: nil)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.StoreManagerDidPurchaseNonConsumable(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init("DidPurchaseNonConsumableProductNotification"), object: nil)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "ReceiptDidUpdated"), object: nil)


SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes()
}





@objc func StoreManagerDidPurchaseNonConsumable(notification:Notification){

guard let id = notification.userInfo?["id"] else {
    return
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


}

//Since this function already update our UI. Let's use it for our receiptDidUpdated
@objc func SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes(){


//Now we need to update the table since we have the products ready

//We need to use the main thread when updating the UI

DispatchQueue.main.async {

    self.indicator.stopAnimating()
    self.tableView.isHidden = false

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)


}



//Selector from cell button (Unlock button)


func didTapCellButton(sender:CustomButton){
let index = sender.index

let product = StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore[index!.row]

StoreManager.shared.buy(product: product)

}
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


// Cell Height
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 165

}

//Number of sections
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}



//Number of rows in section
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //Let's feed our table with the number of products
    return StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore.count


}
func didTapCellButton(_ customButton: CustomButton) {
    print("didTapCellButton")
}    //Cell for row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let product  = StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore[indexPath.row]
    func didTapCellButton(_ customButton: CustomButton) {
        print("didTapCellButton")
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    cell.productName.text = product.localizedTitle
    cell.productDescription.text = product.localizedDescription


    //You should always use NumberFormatter for the price in order to show the correct price currency

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = product.priceLocale

    cell.productPrice.text = formatter.string(from: product.price)

    cell.productStatus.index = indexPath
    cell.productStatus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCellButton), for: .touchUpInside)


    //Let's change the button from Buy to Purchased and change the color as well when the item is already purchased

    if StoreManager.shared.isPurchased(id: product.productIdentifier){

        cell.productStatus.setTitle("Purchased", for: .normal)
        cell.productStatus.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
    }


    //Let's show subscribe button instead of buy

    if StoreManager.shared.autoSubscriptionsIds.contains(product.productIdentifier){

        cell.productStatus.setTitle("Subscribe", for: .normal)

        //Let's change the status of the button if the user is subscribed

        if StoreManager.shared.receiptManager.isSubscribed{
            cell.productStatus.setTitle("Subscribed", for: .normal)
            cell.productStatus.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
        }

    }



    return cell
}




}
```

as requested i added the whole code in here

i hope this works
it really makes no sense why i keep getting the issues. every time i try and change the custom button to make it work i get another error. i used this code fine before in Xcode 8 but since i went to 9 its done this thanks for all the help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass all these parameters in your `#selector`. This is enough and will get rid of your error:

```
cell.productStatus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCellButton), for: .touchUpInside)

func didTapCellButton(_ customButton: CustomButton) {
    print("didTapCellButton")
}
```

Comment: now I'm getting this error from that.Use of local variable 'didTapCellButton' before its declaration.

Comment: You have to declare the didTapCellButton function outside of the function that you´re using your cell...

Comment: this happens when i do that i do not understand! Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'didTapCellButton'

Comment: @KadinLoehr, paste all your code in your question and I´ll take a look. Hard  to help you without any code to see what you have done.

Comment: i have added it

Comment: Declare your `didTapCellButton` function like this: `func didTapCellButton(_ sender: CustomButton) { }`